# How Show in correct order data from two foreach in a one-to-many relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to display data from a one-to-many relationship,

Models:

-Vehicle

```
public function VehicleClient(){
    
            return $this->belongsto(VehicleClient::class,'vehicle_clients_id');
        }
```

-VehicleClient

```
 public function Vehicle(){

        return $this->hasMany(Vehicle::class,'id');
    }
```

Migrations

-Vehicle

```
  Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('color');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

-VehicleClient

```
 Schema::create('vehicle_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('vehicles_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Controller

```
  public function show($id)
    {
     
        $Vehicle =  VehicleClient::where('clients_id',$id)->get();
       return view('clients.show', compact('Vehicles'));
    }
```

Blade:

```
  @foreach($Vehicles as $v)
    @foreach($v->Vehicle as $vehicle)
       <td>{{ $vehicle->nombres }}</td>
     @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

but when doing the two foreach I get a problem adding the relationship property to the second foreach, the property applies to the id of the intermediate table.

this is what the first foreach brings:

| id | vehicles_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |

in the second foreach the property does not execute correctly to fetch the vehicle related to vehicle_id, and the foreach only shows me 2 data instead of 3 with the property, if I remove it it shows me the 3 data

How can I fix that?

Comment: Show us your table in database or your migration file

Comment: I see some mistakes here. One to Many relationship does'nt have intermediate table. The relations are upside down. In the vahicle model goes vehicleClient relation and in the vahicleClient model gos the Vehicles (in plural, not vehicle) function. I think you are relating the vehicle model with itself.

Comment: the query correctly fetches the data from the table into the database

Comment: What do you get if you put `dd($Vehicle->vehicle);` before the return in the controller?

Comment: Exception
Property [Vehicle] does not exist on this collection instance.